# C# VSTO: get current Workbook name from the sheet class

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

In VSTO with Excel workbook (i.e. I am writing a library in C# for a particular workbook, not a general Add-in, I hope it explains it), in a particular sheet class I would like to get a workbook name. Sheet class doesn't seem to have a reference to its workbook. I can get `Application`, but access to `ThisWorkbook` gives an error:

```
MessageBox.Show(this.Application.ThisWorkbook.Name);
```

`this.Parent` doesn't seem to be a `Workbook` either.

The best I could come up with is `Application.ActiveWorkbook` but I wonder if it would be correct all the time?

Comment: ``sheet.Parent`` is a member of one of its base classes, just cast it to workbook and you can access the ``.Name`` member of the workbook. ``((Workbook)sheet.Parent).Name``

Comment: @RandRandom I get the following casting error when I try to cast `Parent` to `Workbook`: `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Workbook'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B74CBB86-9C9F-4172-9AE7-3CE4A7BFA5EB}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).`

Comment: @RandRandom I found the problem! It was taking `Workbook` from a wrong namespace, `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel`, whereas I needed it from `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`. A bit confusing, but it works now.